# Does Kerberos connection to the SQL server needs password to be supplied in connection properties?

Tags: sql-server, kerberos

I am trying to connect to sql server by using keytab and it throws below error

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot login with Kerberos principal DOMAIN\User, check your credentials. Kerberos Login failed: Integrated authentication failed. ClientConnectionId:6f436f49-b0bf-441e-bab3-e6af86ac8361 due to javax.security.auth.login.LoginException (Cannot get any of properties: [password, PASSWORD] from con properties not available to garner  authentication information from the user)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.KerbAuthentication.intAuthInit(KerbAuthentication.java:108)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.KerbAuthentication.GenerateClientContext(KerbAuthentication.java:399)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:4049)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3157)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$100(SQLServerConnection.java:82)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3121)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7151)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2478)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2026)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1687)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1528)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:866)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:569)
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>           at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
>           at com.adventnet.appmanager.server.mssql.datacollection.MSSQLKerberosAuthenticationTest.main(MSSQLKerberosAuthenticationTest.java:47)
>   Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Cannot get any of properties: [password, PASSWORD] from con properties not available to garner  authentication information from the user
>           at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.promptForPass(Unknown Source)
>           at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Unknown Source)
>           at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(Unknown Source)
>           at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(Unknown Source)
>           at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(Unknown Source)
>           at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(Unknown Source)
>           at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.KerbAuthentication.intAuthInit(KerbAuthentication.java:87)
>           ... 15 more

When I try with password it is connected successfully.

```
String home = System.getProperty("user.dir");
String  filePath = home + File.separator + "conf" + File.separator + "KerberosConfigurations" + File.separator + "MSSQL";// NO I18N
System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.debug", "true");
System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", filePath+File.separator+"login.conf");
System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", filePath+File.separator+"krb5.ini");
System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly", "false");
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://"+hostName+":"+port+";databaseName=master;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=true;applicationName=test;"; //NO I18N
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
Properties dbConProp = new Properties();
dbConProp.put("integratedSecurity", "true");
dbConProp.put("authenticationScheme", "JavaKerberos");
dbConProp.put("instanceName",instanceName);
dbConProp.put("user",user);
//dbConProp.put("password",pwd);
con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl,dbConProp);
```

Does password in connection properties is mandatory for kerberos connection? Keytab alone not sufficient ?

Comment: If you are using Kerboros, you don't supply the Username or Password; the connection uses the credentials of the already authenticated Windows Account the application is running as.

Answer (score 2):

The client needs to be authenticated to the domain first. e.g. on Linux and MacOS using [MIT Kerberos](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.12/doc/index.html), you can use the `kinit` command to get a kerberos ticket.

Once granted you can then authenticate to Sql via that ticket without supplying anything else.

**[Update]**

If your host and target are both on a Windows domain *and* they're on the same domain, then you should already be good to go.

That said, Sql will **only** allow you to authenticate using Kerberos *if* the service account that is running the engine has privileges to create a [Service Principal Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/register-a-service-principal-name-for-kerberos-connections?view=sql-server-2017) (or a user with appropriate rights has created a **SPN** with the `setSPN` command).

You can tell if Sql's been able to register the **SPN** by looking at the Sql Error Log for text like

`The SQL Server Network Interface library successfully registered the Service Principal Name (SPN) [ MSSQLSvc/MySqlServerHostName:1433 ] for the SQL Server service`

There's a lot to Kerberos than can be covered in just a *StackOverflow* Answer.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Can you please tell me when keytab will be supplied? I mean these configurations


System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.debug", "true");
System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", filePath+File.separator+"login.conf");
System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", filePath+File.separator+"krb5.ini");
System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly", "false");

Comment: You didn't specify an OS, so here's something I found for Windows: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/pie/2018/01/03/all-you-need-to-know-about-keytab-files/

Comment: Thank you for that. Yes it is windows.. But my doubt is just by throwing kinit and without using keytab can we connect to SQL server?

Comment: Yes, if your keytab is generated correctly. The page I gave you has full instructions to generate the keytab

Comment: Thanks for responding. My question is without using keytab can we connect to SQL server just by throwing kinit command.

Comment: Yes - That was my original answer. This all said, if both servers are on the same domain then you don't need to worry about it anyway.

Comment: Thanks Rachel. Can you check this post and input your thoughts.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57051842/spn-not-available-in-the-keytab-file